# Get Aggregate Data From CTE

Tags: postgresql, t-sql, performance, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

I have a CTE statement that returns line item information for me.  This is great, but I need to manipulate this in order to only get aggregate counts by Employee where the criteria is met.  For example data when this query is executed this is returned

```
Employee saleid   SaleAmt  SaleDate
Emp A    abc123   1100  2017-01-03
Emp A    def456   1200  2017-01-03
Emp B    ghi789   1500  2017-01-09
```

Now all that I want returned is

```
Employee  Count
Emp A 2
Emp B 1
```

How should this query be modified in order to only return aggregate data?
**Note I am using the `RTRIM()` and the `LTRIM()` functions as sometimes a user will input extra whitespace before or after an employee name (cleanup is going to take place soon :)--)

```
WITH DollaAmt AS 
(
    Select 
    cm.empName employee
    ,jb.saleID saleID
    ,CAST(COALESCE(jp.saleamt,0) As DOUBLE PRECISION) DollaAmt
    ,CAST(jp.saleDate As Date) saleDate
    FROM salePieces jp
    Inner Join sale jb
    on jp.saleID = jb.saleID
    Inner join employee cm
    on cm.esID = jb.esID
    WHERE jp.saleDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
    AND cm.empStatus IN ('A', 'E', 'L')
    OR RTRIM(LTRIM(cm.empName)) = 'Trainee'
),
employees As
(
    select 
    cm.empName As Employee
    ,cm.empStatus As employeeStatus
    FROM employee cm
    ORDER BY Employee ASC
)
Select
DISTINCT(RTRIM(LTRIM(Employee))) As "employeeName"
,ia.saleID
,"TotalDollaAmt"
,ia.saleDate
FROM employees cm
JOIN (
        Select
        RTRIM(LTRIM(employee)) As employee
        ,SUM(DollaAmt) As "TotalDollaAmt"
        ,saleDate
        ,saleID
        FROM DollaAmt 
        GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(employee)),saleDate,saleID
) As ia
ON RTRIM(LTRIM(ia.employee)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(cm.Employee))
WHERE CAST(saleDate As Date) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
AND "TotalDollaAmt" >= '1000.00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to change your outer query to also GROUP BY the employee name:

```
...
SELECT
(RTRIM(LTRIM(Employee))) As "employeeName"
,COUNT(1) AS "Count"
FROM employees cm
JOIN (
        Select
        RTRIM(LTRIM(employee)) As employee
        ,SUM(DollaAmt) As "TotalDollaAmt"
        ,saleDate
        ,saleID
        FROM DollaAmt 
        GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(employee)),saleDate,saleID
) As ia
ON RTRIM(LTRIM(ia.employee)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(cm.Employee))
WHERE CAST(saleDate As Date) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
AND "TotalDollaAmt" >= '1000.00'
GROUP BY (RTRIM(LTRIM(Employee)))
```